# Using C++ dlls in event receiver

Tags: development, visual-studio, event-handlers, assembly-references

I am trying to use a legacy C++ dll that has around 5 C/C++ dependencies in SharePoint. I created a wrapper for the dll and it works fine in a test desktop program. I added the wrapper and all C++ libraries to the event receiver assembly and they are being deployed to the WebApplication target.  When I run the receiver I get

> SecurityException was unhandled by user code System.Security.Permission.SecurityPermission

when it hits the C++ method.

Next, I tried using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` in the wrapper but I get

> SecurityException was unhandled by user code Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission`.

How can I get the C++ library to work?

Comment: Can you post a little more code, like exactly how you are using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This isn't a SP security issue, it's a file system security issue. 
>   Make sure the identity running this code has permissions to read the
>   file system.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/76931dc2-ef34-4ef6-a1d9-228688010adb)

Make sure your C++ library has sufficient file permissions so that SharePoint can access it. You can match permissions with your development environment.

Other then that all I can think of is trust levels of your web application, check this [link](http://sharepointquery.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/moss-trust-level-and-code-access.html) out that is explaining how trust levels are setup in different environment as your development machine web app might have full trust level.

Comment: I worked off your comment and was able to find [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261736%28v=office.14%29.aspx#BKMK_SettingSecurity) which allowed talked about AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers. Calling that assembly along with changing the web.config `<trust level='Full'>` allowed the dll to execute. Thanks for your help!